# Automate Login To Zimbra Server

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, automation, zimbra

I am making a webpage that has a login functionality in it say www.newpage.com.
Below is the code of the page for reference.

```
<form name="login">
Username<input type="text" name="userid"/>
Password<input type="password" name="pswrd"/>
<input type="button" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login"/>
<input type="reset" value="Cancel"/>
</form>
<script language="javascript">
function check(form)
{
 if(form.userid.value == "user" && form.pswrd.value == "password")
  {
    window.open('file:///C:/Users/target.html', "_self")
    window.open('https://webmail.sas.rutgers.edu/')
}
   alert("Error Password or Username")
  }
}
```

Now what I want is after i have logged in to this webpage it should automatically login to my local Zimbra server. The look and feel of zimbra server is like this : https://webmail.sas.rutgers.edu/

I am learning Javascript so not sure what is the way of doing it.
I read that it can be done by:

1)  iframes (again don't know much about them)

2) cookies

Is there a way to do it more conveniently, preferring to do in Javascript. I am stuck with some important project please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is too broad and is not easy to be answered in short. But let's say you want to login into one particular existing mailbox/account, then one of the easiest ways to do it is to use the zimbra's preauth service and once you log's in your site you could redirect to that service url with specific request parameters which in turn creates and verifies a preauth key and redirects you to your mailbox. Of course you need to configure the preauth properly first. Here is the official guide for it https://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Preauth